# icelink 3. How to record local+remote video?

Tags: video-streaming, video-recording

I am using icelink 3 for video conferencing. I want to allow users to record conference video. Is there any way by which I can record local+remote video into same file either using javascript library or java library?

Answer (score 0):

I did it successfully by using [recordRTC](https://recordrtc.org/) with icelink.

Include RecordRTC.js to you page and use follwing script to record local and remote audio/video in single file.

```
// On start Record :
var options = {
                mimeType: 'video/webm;', // or video/webm\;codecs=h264 or video/webm\;codecs=vp9
                audioBitsPerSecond: 256000,
                videoBitsPerSecond: 256000,             
               };

var recordRTC = RecordRTC([this.localMedia._internal._getVideoMediaStream(), 
                           connection.getRemoteMedia()._getInternal()._videoMediaStream], 
                           options);
recordRTC.startRecording();

//on Stop recording: 
 recordRTC.stopRecording(function (audioVideoWebMURL) {
                recordRTC.getDataURL(function (dataURL) { });
                var btnDownloadVideoEl = document.createElement('a');
                document.body.appendChild(btnDownloadVideoEl);
                btnDownloadVideoEl.href = audioVideoWebMURL;
                btnDownloadVideoEl.download = 'TeleHealthRecording.webm';
                btnDownloadVideoEl.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(audioVideoWebMURL);
                recordRTC = null;
            });
```

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam, Getting this error while trying to replicate what you mentioned-- [IceLink][1][1] ERROR   [FM][-] 2018/11/01-18:00:14.484 An exception in user code (Client -> JoinConference -> OnRemoteClient) was unhandled. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getVideoTracks' of null

Comment: videoMediaStream object I am trying to access using --connection.getRemoteMedia()._getInternal()._videoMediaStream  is null